# How does modulo % work in python

Tags: python, operators, modulo

I tried `21.1%10.2` the answer was `.7` but it should be rather `7`. Can anyone please explain how the answer is `.7`

Comment: Why do you think it should be 7?

Comment: 0.7 is the correct [answer](https://www.google.com/#q=21.1%20mod%2010.2&rct=j)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate - the answer is 0.7 not 7. 21.1 divided by 10.2 is 2 with remainder 0.7

Answer (score 5):

It will be .7 only.

If you divide 21.1 by 10.2 the reminder will be .7.

```
21.2 % 10.2
```

It could be explain like simple divide of the nos.

```
10.2 * 2 =  20.4

21.1 - 20.4 = .7
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: But if we do this 212/102 the reminder will be 7 and 212/102 is equal to 21.2/10.2. Also if we do this using basic mathematics multiplying and dividing by 10 then reminder will be 7.Then why is the remainder 7?

Comment: @SashaktPathak Just because the quotients are equal doesn't mean the remainders are. And by the way - the remainder of 212/102 is 8. Just think about it: The remainder of 100 / 90 is 10. Does that mean that the remainder of 10 / 9 is 10? No, that is clearly false.

Comment: If you upscale the operands, the remainder will be upscaled as well.

Comment: sorry I was typing 211/102